# React error with create-react-app command

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd

I have been facing a weird situations while creating a react app via command line on windows 10. I get the following error when I run create-react-app command. I am using node v8.9.4 and npm v6.4.0.

```
Creating a new React app in D:\react\myreactapp. 

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. 
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts... 

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^1.0.1","line-numbers' 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-26T11_04_03_908Z-debug.log 

Aborting installation. 
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed. 

Deleting generated file... package.json 
Deleting myreactapp / from D:\react 
Done.
```

Comment: run `react-native info` and edit the question with the result.

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with the project name you gave it. Try using dragon-case, i.e. only lower case and hyphens.  So instead of

```
$ create-react-native-app myApp
```

use

```
$ create-react-native-app my-app
```

or from the error message, could it be that after the app name (myreactapp) you added a space and then pressed the back-slash instead of Enter, before pressing Enter again?

Also, try: `npm cache clean --force`

and if that doesn't do the trick: `yarn cache clean`

It may have been caused by a missing linebreak in the React-Native installation instructions in the Readme (that has been fixed since), between `npm install` and `npm start` causing users to do `npm install npm start` - which was installing `npm` itself with all its tests. See issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20015.

In any case it would be good if you ran `react-native info` and told us the result.